# How Can I Include glew32.dll Without Having To Put It In system Root

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, dll, glew

How Can I add glew32.dll to visual Studios 2010 without having to put it in system root direction.

I followed a few online examples of adding glew32.dll all come to the same answer to just put it in the system root.

But just for studies sake.

Is there a way to include glew32.dll to Visual Studios 2010 without having to put it in the system root directory.

If you have an answer reply with an example of how to do so.

Comment: Why not avoid using the DLL version of GLEW altogether and just link to the static library? Then you don't have to worry about where you put the DLL because it will not be needed. Your binary size might increase, but that's usually not a big issue.

Comment: I just followed wrangler linking to do that. might you have an example  on how to set that one up? I try to avoid linking when possible since I have nightmares from a project I did once that had like 10 includes which needed each other. The headaches lol

Answer (score 3):

#### This does not answer your original question, but demonstrates how to avoid the issue.

Ordinarily I would not "answer" something this way, but there really are next to no benefits to using the DLL version of glew. It is not like you can pop a new version of this DLL in and take advantage of new features, you have to know about the extensions at the time you compiled your software originally.

To avoid having to ship `glew32.dll` with your software you can link to `glew32s.lib`. Your .exe will grow in size, but not substantially and you probably would have had to ship `glew32.dll` anyway so the difference in size is moot.

#### The easiest thing to do would be to take advantage of a special `#pragma` for MSVC's compiler:

```c
#define GLEW_STATIC // This must be defined when statically linking to GLEW
#include "glew.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "glew32s.lib") // Link to glew32s.lib
```

Alternatively, you can setup libraries in your project settings, but that involves going through the MSVC GUI and I do not have a copy of Visual Studio 2010 to show you how that is done.

Comment: i did that. but my project is still complaining that I don't have glew32.dll

Comment: Make sure you remove any project settings that reference `glew32.lib`.

Comment: wait im confused >.> i thought my goal was to include glew32.lib rather than the .dll why would i remove any glew32.lib reference.

Comment: No, `glew32.lib` is only half of the equation. That is the *dynamic* library you link to, which depends on `glew32.dll`. `glew32s.lib` (the ***s*** might be hard to notice, but it makes a huge difference) is a different type of library (static) that does not depend on a DLL at runtime. If you want to use the static linking version, you need to remove the dynamic linking version from your project settings.

Comment: i skip pragma comments because they are so windows specific and its just so easy to do it that way lol.

but thanks all your info really helped out its all working now. besides my devIL.dll missing error even though im using the libs for that one too X_X

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to include glew32.dll to Visual Studios 2010 without having to put it in the system root directory.

Don't think of it as something you want to add to VS. Instead think of it as an asset of the program you're building: Just copy the DLL into the same folder of the EXE of your program. Windows will look there first for DLLs before it even goes looking for it in the system directories.

Of course GLEW is so small, that it probably is the better choice so simply link it statically.

Comment: There is one interesting point of note though. The Visual Studio IDE sets the working directory at run-time to the project's root directory when you run it through the debugger, and you can put the DLL there to make life easier. It comes in handy when you have 5 or 6 build configurations (instead of putting the same DLL in each of those build configuration directories).